# c programming regarding arrays and minimum?

Tags: c

Build a program which reads from the user an array with n elements and finds the element with the smallest value.Then the program finds the number of the elements which have an equal value with this minimum.The found element with the smallest value along with the number of the elements which have an equal value with the minimum of the array should be displayed on screen..

I wrote this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n = 1, min = 0, count = 0;
  int number[n];

  printf("Enter the size of array you want");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  int x;
  for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter a Integer");
    scanf("%i", &num); 
    number[x] = num;
    if (number[x] < min)
      min = number[x];
  }
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (min = number[i])
      count++; 
  }
  printf("%s%i", "\nThe smallest Integer you entered was ", min);
  printf("%s%i", "\nNumber of times you entered this Integer: ", count);

  return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that when I run this,and I add the integers,it doesnt find the smallest value and how time its repeated correctly!

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `if (min = number[i])` is not a comparison. And your `int number[n]` will not work right, because the value of `n` is changed *after* this array is declared. (And check the return value of `scanf` instead of blindly assuming it succeeded.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are checking array element <0 in line:

```
if (number[x] < min/*as u specified min =0 before*/),...
```

so the minimum is set to be zero and there is no replacement actually happening..

The full solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n = 1, min = 0, count = 0;
  int number[n];

  printf("Enter the size of array you want");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  int x,y;
  for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
  {
     printf("\nEnter a Integer");
     scanf("%i", &number[y]);
  } 
  min=number[0];
  for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {

    if (number[x] < min)
      min = number[x];
  }
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (min == number[i])
      count++; 
  }
  printf("%s%i", "\nThe smallest Integer you entered was ", min);
  printf("%s%i", "\nNumber of times you entered this Integer: ", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there are a couple of bugs here.  You can't safely declare the VLA `number` before you've initialised `n`.  If `n` is set to `0`, accessing `number[0]` will cause you to read unallocated memory, resulting in undefined behaviour

Comment: i wrote the code i a hurry..you are welcome to make any changes.. :) @simonc

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your compiler has support for variable length arrays, you need to re-order the calls

```
int number[n];
scanf("%i", &n);
```

so that you know the value for `n` before declaring the array

```
scanf("%i", &n);
int number[n];
```

After that, you should initialise `min` to a larger value to avoid ignoring all positive values

```
int min = INT_MAX;
```

(You'll need to include `<limits.h>` for the definition of `INT_MAX`)

Finally,

```
if (min = number[i])
```

assigns `number[i]` to `min`.  Use `==` to test for equality.

Your compiler should have warned you about "assignment in conditional statement" for this last point.  If it didn't, make sure you have enabled warnings (`-Wall` with gcc, `/W4` with MSVC)

Comment: You don't need int min to be = INT_MAX, a quicker way is just have it be initialized to the first entry.

Comment: @Ion Agreed that this would be possible. I'd say its more complicated than the code I suggested - you'd have to check for n==0 before accessing number[0]

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (min = number[i])
      count++; 
  }
```

Replace `min = number[i]` with `min == number[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

1.Only After the user input the array size, then you can determine the size of the array number.As the size of the array are uncertain, you should use **malloc** to allocate the array dynamically.

2.you should set min to the first element of the array. As the min of user input may be great than zero, if you set min to zero, then it will return zero even though the minimum is great than zero

3.you should **use == but not = to test the equality of two numbers**.

4.last, you should use **free** to make the memory available and avoid memory leak.

Below is the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n = 1, min = 0, count = 0;
int* number;

printf("Enter the size of array you want");
scanf("%i", &n);
number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

int x;
for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter a Integer");
    scanf("%i", &num); 
    number[x] = num;

    if( x == 0  || number[x] < min )
    min = number[x];
}
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (min == number[i])
        count++; 
}
printf("%s%i", "\nThe smallest Integer you entered was ", min);
printf("%s%i", "\nNumber of times you entered this Integer: ", count);

free(number);
number = NULL;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: It would be worth adding some text to explain what code you've changed and why.  Also, you're missing a `free(number);` call towards the end of the function.

Comment: I have added some text, is that Ok?

Comment: Great (+1).  Rather than just solving the OP's current problem, this'll now help him/her understand how to solve similar issues in future too.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if (min = number[i])
```

you assigned number[i] to min. You should write

```
if (min == number[i])
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong on your code. First you defined array `number[1]`. Secondly `min` in initialised to `min = 0`.

I suggest defined the array for a maximum possible size, like `number[100]`. And read the numbe of inputs `n` from the user, and only use the first `n` elements of the array. For the second issue, define min as the maximum number represented by `int` type.